# unable to get the information on succeess page after paypal success

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

i am using paypal standard code in my website but after successful payment i not get any information on success page.

and how to get the transaction id, amount and other detail from paypal page.

my code is this :

payment.php page

```
<?php 
 $paypal_url='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; // Test Paypal API URL
 $paypal_id='ankur.garg@trignodev.com'; // Business email ID
?>

<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='<?php echo $product_name;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='<?php echo $product_price;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='<?php echo $base;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='<?php echo $base;?>index.php?route=product/creditsuccess'>
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now">
 </form>
```

and success.php

```
<?php 
$item_transaction = $_REQUEST['tx'];
$item_price = $_POST['amount']; // Paypal received amount

echo "your payment is successfully";
echo "and here is the detail:";

echo $item_transaction;
echo $item_price;
?>
```

please help me to get the transaction id, amount and payment_status on success page.

Answer (score 0):

that's not right way...you have to pass all values which you get in post method as a querystring to paypal....use this function, it might be useful to you...

Now change your form line from  this,

```
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now">
```

to,

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">
```

Now On top of the page,

Call function like this

```
function PaypalPayment($paypal_email,$return_url,$cancel_url,$notify_url,$post)
{
    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";  
    foreach($post as $key => $value)
    {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }
        $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
        $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
        $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr<?php echo      $querystring;?>';  
            /*  window.location = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr<?php //echo $querystring;?>'; */
        </script><?php
        exit();
}

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   $success_url = // Here Goes Success URL
   $cancel_url = // Here Goes Cancel URL
   $notify_url = // Here Goes Current Page URL

   $payid = // Enter Your merchant id

   PaypalPayment($payid,$success_url,$cancel_url,$notify_url,$_POST);   
  }
```

Now Simply Call this function, pass all your urls & paypal email ...
in $post pass your post data of form ($_POST)

Comment: i not understan your code i simply want to get transaction id, payment notification detail and other data so please help me to give full code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your Source code is not an issue. You have to do some settings in PayPal.
Login with PayPal Business account and Post the below link in the browser.
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website#

Here we have to set the "ON" option for **PDT** as well as **auto-return**.
Refer to this screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]